# Easy way to increment Mongoose document versions for any update queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to start taking advantage of Mongooses document versioning (__v key). I was having an issue actually incrementing the version value, then I found that you have to add `this.increment()` when executing a query.

Is there a way to have automatically incremented? For now, I just added it to the **pre** middleware for a update-type queries:

```js
module.exports = Mongoose => {
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    const modelSchema = new Schema( {
        name: Schema.Types.String,
        description: Schema.Types.String
    } )

    // Any middleware that needs to be fired off for any/all update-type queries
    _.forEach( [ 'save', 'update', 'findOneAndUpdate' ], query => {
        // Increment the Mongoose (__v)ersion for any updates
        modelSchema.pre( query, function( next ) {
            this.increment()
            next()
        } )
    } )
}
```

Which seems to work.. But I kinda thought there would already be a way to do this within Mongoose.. am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd say this is the way to go. **pre** middleware fits exactly this need, and I don't know any other way. In fact this is what I'm doing in all my schemas.

What you need to be aware of though, is the difference between *document* and *query* middleware.
**Document** middleware are executed for `init`, `validate`, `save` and `remove` operations. There, `this` refers to the document:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.increment();
  return next();
});
```

**Query** middleware are executed for `count`, `find`, `findOne`, `findOneAndRemove`, `findOneAndUpdate` and `update` operations. There, `this` refers to the query object. Updating the version field for such operations would look like this:

```
schema.pre('update', function( next ) {
  this.update({}, { $inc: { __v: 1 } }, next );
});
```

Source: [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

Comment: So you're saying I would have to split up the `__v` incrementation between the document update methods (`save`) and the query update methods (`findOneAndUpdate`, `update`)? Something like **[this](http://pastebin.com/QGxgLhQz)**?

Comment: Yes, you have to split the incrementation between document and query middlewares. I suggest having 2 different methods as shown in my post, rather than trying to squeeze 2 different ways in a single method.

Comment: FYI @Antoine, the Query MW function needed the `next` callback, which I found out from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540047/incorrect-document-revision-number-found-in-post-update-middleware). I updated your post

Comment: For some reason, if I put `next` beside the query update it increments in a step of 2

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest way to do that is :

```
clientsController.putClient = async (req, res) => {

const id = req.params.id;
const data = req.body;
data.__v++;

await Clients.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, data)
    .then( () => 
    {
        res.json(Ok);
    }
    ).catch ( err => {
        Error.code = '';
        Error.error = err;
        res.json(Error);
    })
```

};