# Incorrect document revision number found in post update middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-plugins

I have a Mongoose plugin which I use to increment the documents revision number (`__v`), as well as create revision itself. The plugin covers the Documents `Doc.save()` middleware function, as well as the Query `update` and `findOneAndUpdate` middleware functions.

```js
module.exports = ( schema, options ) => {
    _.forEach( [ 'save','update', 'findOneAndUpdate' ], query => {
        // Since the Doc.save() middleware is the only document update middleware function, just isolate that one
        if( query === 'save' )
            schema.pre( query, function( next ) {
                this.increment()
                next()
            } )

        // The rest are query updates
        else
            schema.pre( query, function() {
                this.update( {}, { $inc: { __v: 1 } } )
            })


        // Create revisions for each document update
        schema.post( query, docData => {
            Mongoose.models.Revision.createRevision( {
                docsId: this._id,
                revision: docData.__v, // <-- This is the wrong number. It's one less than it should be
                document: { /* Stuff.. */ }
                // More stuff
            }, ( err, revision ) => {
                // CB Stuff
            })
        })
    })
}
```

So this mostly works as expected. The `__v` value of the document gets incremented for both document and query interactions, and the revision documents get created as well. The part that i'm stuck on, is related to the Query middleware functions, `update` and `findOneAndUpdate`. Even though the `__v` gets updated in the document via the **pre** event, the `this.__v` value in the **post** event doesn't seem to see the updated value. So that means the revision gets created and references the incorrect revision number of the document.

This is just super weird, because the documents `__v` **does** in fact get updated when I look at it in the database, but when I *console.log* the `this.__v`in the *post* `update`.. it sees the revision number prior to it being updated..

For a temporary fix, I just increment it manually, if its a query MW function:

```js
schema.post( query, docData => {
    Mongoose.models.Revision.createRevision( {
        docsId: this._id,
        revision: ( query === 'save' // Temporary fix..
            ? docData.__v
            : docData.__v+1 ) // Add +1 if its a query function 
        document: { /* Stuff.. */ }
        // More stuff
    }, ( err, revision ) => {
        // CB Stuff
    })
})
```

But obviously, this is just a bandaid, so if theres a real fix for this, that would be great

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though the `__v` gets updated in the document via the **pre** event, the `this.__v` value in the post event doesn't seem to see the updated value.

That's most likely because your middleware for `update` and `findOneAndUpdate` isn't using an async callback to wait for the action to finish before continuing( something that you *did* implement for the `save` middleware).

So make it use the callback:

```
schema.pre( query, function(next) {
  this.update( {}, { $inc: { __v : 1 } }, next);
})
```

Comment: Ohhh... I actually wondered why it didn't have the `next` in there, I actually took it pretty much right from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288488/easy-way-to-increment-mongoose-document-versions-for-any-update-queries), I guess I should have looked into it further.. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed the same (a missing callback) in an example mentioned in the Mongoose documentation, although there it was updating a field that probably wasn't going to be used in subsequent queries/middleware. I guess the author left out the callback for conciseness reasons (not necessarily a great idea, as it can confuse people).